# EF6 "se produjo una excepcion en el inicializador de tipo 'MyContext' "

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2019

estoy tratando de visualizar el modelo gráfico de mi DbContext con mis clases POCO, utilizando la herramienta **EntityFramework 6 PowerTools Community Edition**. Antes de realizar la migración a la Base de Datos.
Pero se genera una excepcion cuando doy *click derecho sobre NombreDbContext.cs > **View Entity Data Model***  en el explorador de soluciones. Se muestra un cuadro de dialogo que dice *"se produjo una excepción en el inicializador de tipo 'NombreProyecto.NombreDbContext' "*.

Mi archivo App.config es

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NombreDbContext" connectionString="server=myserver;user id=myuser;password=mypass;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=myDatabase" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.10.8.0" newVersion="6.10.8.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**NOTA: Estoy usando

ENTITYFRAMEWORK 6.2.0

MYSQL SERVER 8.0

MYSQL CONNECTOR 6.10.8

VISUALSTUDIO 2019 COMMUNITY EDITION**

De Antemano muchas gracias a quien me pueda ayudar!

Tenia una sobrecarga del constructor declarado de esta manera

```
  static NativoContext()
        {
            DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration());
        }
```

al obviar esto me dio una nueva excepcion(mucho mas extensa) en un cuadro de dialogo.

[image: Este es el primer cuadro de dialogo]

[image: Al clickear **Omitir** sale este segundo cuadro de dialogo]

Comment: ¿Has intentado dar un clean/rebuild?

Comment: estas seguro que esa Power tools funcina con MySql ? si tienes una db Sql Server a mano podrias crearte una db de prueba con una o dos tablas y ver de aplicar la Power tools a ver si con esta db funciona, si lo hace queda claro que el provider no esta bien integrado

Comment: @fredyfx Hice lo que me recomendaste y aun asi no funciona, Gracias igualmente.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Segui tus recomendaciones y efectivamente con el proveedor de Microsoft para SQL Server, funciono la herramienta sin problemas, sabras si existira alguna herramienta parecida que sea soportada por MySql??? El proposito por el que quiero usar esa herramienta es porque necesito copiar una BD que esta muy mal estructurada y necesito ver como se comportan las relaciones entre las entidades, ya que, trabajando con MySql resulta engorroso como se comporta EF6

Comment: pero para ver como se relaciona las tablas de MySql no necesitas una tool que se integre con entity framewor, podrias usar un manager propio de mysql https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: @LeandroTuttini, es que si utilizo el workbench. El problema esta en que la BD ya existe, pero cuando hago CodeFirst from Database, debido a que no utilizaron ninguna convencion para el nombre de los campos ni de las tablas(mas de 300 tablas), se crean un desastre de clases POCO, las cuales tendre que modificar a mano en muchas de las propiedades, y temo que esto afecte la relacion cuando quiera hacer un CodeFirst a una nueva BD, no se si me explico bien. Acepto recomendaciones...Gracias de antemano...

Comment: no entiendo que quieres lograr, una cosa es analizar la db para entenderla y otra es volcar el maping de mas de 300 tablas como entidades de EF, lo cual al ser tantas tablas quizas deberias ir agregando de a poco de forma controlada mapeando las relaciones a mano, llevara su tiempo pero tendras el controles y solo mapeas lo que vayas a utilizar

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Muchas gracias por el aporte!, eso justamene estaba pensando en hacer pero no me decidia. Voy a chequear los videos de tu blog sobre codefirst, Saludos y muchas gracias!